# Created forms from JSON Schema, How to add Close button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui, getjson

With this https://github.com/joshfire/jsonform I have created Form.

```
$('form').jsonForm({
    schema: {
        name: {type: 'string', title: 'Name', required: true},
        //age: {type: 'number', title: 'Age', required: true},
        comment: {type: 'textarea', title: 'Comments', required: true},             
        choice: {type: 'string',title: 'Title', 'enum': ['choice-1','choice-2','choice-3']},

    },          
    onSubmit: function (errors, values) {
      if (errors) {
        $('#res').html('<p>I beg your pardon?</p>');
      }
      else {
        $('#res').html('<p>Hello ' + values.name + '.' +
          (values.comment ? '<br/>You are ' + values.comment + '.' : '') +
          '</p>');
      }
    }
});
```

In this By Default Submit button is present.

But I want to add **"Close"** button.

Or How can I **remove** or hide that Default **"Submit"** button, so that I will add other submit and close button?

Comment: Consider overriding the jsonform & either add the close button yourself on hide the default submit button.

Comment: They have pretty awesome documentation. https://github.com/joshfire/jsonform/wiki#wiki-fields-buttons

Comment: methinks the documentation on adding custom buttons is not straight forward. @eegloo Check out my answer below on adding custom buttons.

Comment: @srvikram13 : thanks for your answer. ".form-actions {display:none;}" this added in CSS file. This is also working

Comment: @Pedram Behroozi: Yes I have this link, thank you. But some part are not straight forward. That is why confused. ".form-actions {display:none;}" is added in CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('form').jsonForm({
    ...code
}); 
// Save reference to parent element to append custom buttons
var btn-container = $('form input[type=submit]').parent();

// Remove default 'submit' button
$('form input[type=submit]').remove();

// now add custom buttons in btn-container
```